# QML: Is there an opportunity to create ListModel using <for loop>, and then using loop index on calculating ListModel item coordinates?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I need to create many similar elements, that differ only by coordinates.

I learned how to create this one by one:

```
 Repeater {
            model: ListModel {
            
                ListElement { p:100; q:100; w:50; h:50; c:"red"; o:0 }
                ListElement { p:200; q:100; w:50; h:50; c:"red"; o:0 }
                ListElement { p:300; q:100; w:50; h:50; c:"red"; o:0 }
                ListElement { p:400; q:100; w:50; h:50; c:"red"; o:0 }
                ListElement { p:500; q:100; w:50; h:50; c:"red"; o:0 }
                        }
                        delegate: Rectangle {
                            x: p
                            y: q
                            width: w
                            height: h
                            color: c
                            rotation: o
                        }
                    }
```

I have now come to the conclusion that it would be convenient to do this with a simple for loop, using the loop index when calculating the coordinates:

```
 Repeater {
            model: ListModel {
            
              for ( var i = 1; i <= 5; i++ )
                {
                ListElement { p:100*i; q:100; w:50; h:50; c:"red"; o:0 }
                }
                        }
                        delegate: Rectangle {
                            x: p
                            y: q
                            width: w
                            height: h
                            color: c
                            rotation: o
                        }
                    }
```

Unfortunately, there is a problem with loop scope, and of course I don't even expect it will work in that shape...
I am trying to show only my idea in the second code.

Is there an opportunity to create ListElements like this or am I confusing two different ways of item creating?

Comment: Please read the qml tutorials and docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#append-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example, I highly recommend @folibis answer as that demonstrates the usage of `index` and `modelData` which both are most appropriate for your scenario.

Generally speaking, you can mix QML/Javascript, you just need more practice in knowing the correct syntax/context where you can use QML and where you can use Javascript. Also, there are legimite scenarios where you want to populate a `ListModel` programmatically.

In the following demo, a `ListModel` is populated programmatically in JavaScript imperatively. In fact, it is even executed after all the QML components are initialized, so, the `Repeater` actually initially sees an  empty `ListModel`. Whilst executing the `populate` function, each `append` signals changes to the `ListModel` which your `Repeater` will acknowledge through incremental updates.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Repeater {
        model: listModel
        delegate: Rectangle {
            x: p
            y: q
            width: w
            height: h
            color: c
            rotation: o
        }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: listModel
        function populate() {
            for ( let i = 1; i <= 5; i++ )
            {
                listModel.append( { p:100*i, q:100, w:50, h:50, c:"red", o:0 } );
            }
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: listModel.populate()
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACHHicbVExbsMwDNz9ikMmuzEMZ8iiNFPWFmj6A0NmbKGKqCgy3CLw3ysVrWMVuYE6nkiKB6mzZedx9MdByY9MJWl1YOMd62v21nSEW4aAd7LUeHK/acSZW9ICWl39a6TzReDUhWIRuqRvTKdp0RbxKWAT4Uvgkgijan0vMCZiT6rrvUCfqJI1OwGZiI594xUbAZ71KbvHl7+tF5up9pGb02BknATLdtDBVl78c3NihxyaPBT22OzC8bzHNpzrNYqkNG2MmB+sGmvJtDlusGJT10+qxCWSEqPYhtj/RClWjtpVCRY1JhS7ZOL00OyBwwcbMr5iE3lYlZZeq7u1bPoGUBOItw==)

Some time ago, when I was playing around with QML with the kids, we mocked up a "Click Invaders" game. The game has the following features:

- ListModel will contain the position of the invaders
- Repeater is used to render the invaders
- Timer object is used to guarantee to make 10 invaders slowly appear on the screen
- When the user clicks, the invader will "die" and be removed - this will trigger more invaders to spawn

Check it out. It has some concepts such as using SVG to render the graphic. It dynamically creates and destroys objects in different positions and orientations:

https://github.com/stephenquan/qmlonline6/wiki/Example-Click-Invaders

Comment: Thanks Stephen! Of course I am checking this now. I am gonna create a few very simple games in QML: Snake, Tetris, Asteroids, maybe Arkanoid. Just for education purposes.  Althought QML is very well documented on doc.io.qt,  it is hard to judge which types should be learned first. Thanks again, you have speed up my education during first days of learning this material.

Comment: Ok, you may be interested in https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-promises-demo and the Google Play version https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stephenquan.qt5promisedemo - where I have a bunch of async programming examples using yield/generator in place of async/await to create demos. This programming pattern, IMHO, makes creating animations and games simpler - hence why I created the library. However, this may all change when async/await arrives in Qt6.6.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will take a look at your GH. Anyway, the conversations in my QML topics have helped me a lot. I think I finally know how to go about learning Qt Quick. Regards

Comment: I've created a new example snippet implementing a basic snake (no collision detection, nor eating, nor tail growing added): https://github.com/stephenquan/qmlonline6/wiki/Example-Snake

Comment: Thanks for example. I also work on Snake now, and it looks like I reached a tiny progress last hours. I have conrolable one-segment snake, "food" appears at random screen coordinates and I have detection snake/food colision. But I think it is not time to show code yet. I still need to spend time on getting model/delegate idea, but now I can see last days was worth of effort.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, before you start writing a program, you need to learn the basics. You can't mix `QML` and `Javascript` in this way. It also seems to me that `ListElement` is completely out of place here.

Here's how it can be rewritten:

```js
Repeater {
    model: 5
    delegate: Rectangle {
        x: 100 * index
        y: 100
        width: 50
        height: 50
        color: "red"
        rotation: 0
    }
}
```

If you need more control over the data, you can change to this:

```js
Repeater {
    model: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    delegate: Rectangle {
        x: 100 * modelData
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: My apologies, I was convinced that the loop for is a normal component of the QML language syntax

Answer (score 0):

A very important section of the documentation to start with when coming to Qt Quick without JavaScript knowledge:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-javascript-expressions.html

It's a must-see here if you didn't expect that you'll need to learn something besides C++ along with Qt.

> The JavaScript environment provided by QML is stricter than that     in a web browser. For example, in QML you cannot add to, or modify, members of the JavaScript global object. In regular JavaScript, it is possible to do this accidentally by using a variable without declaring it. In QML this will throw an exception, so all local variables must be explicitly declared. See JavaScript Environment Restrictions for a complete description of the restrictions on JavaScript code executed from QML.
>
> Various parts of QML documents can contain JavaScript code:
>
> The body of property bindings. These JavaScript expressions describe relationships between QML object properties. When dependencies of a property change, the property is automatically updated too, according to the specified relationship.
> The body of Signal handlers. These JavaScript statements are automatically evaluated whenever a QML object emits the associated signal.
> The definition of custom methods. JavaScript functions that are defined within the body of a QML object become methods of that object.
> Standalone JavaScript resource (.js) files. These files are actually separate from QML documents, but they can be imported into QML documents. Functions and variables that are defined within the imported files can be used in property bindings, signal handlers, and custom methods.

Should carefully distinguish between JavaScript and QML elements in Qt Quick. If QML is a language for creating a GUI, its elements are the types described in doc.qt.io. On the other hand, loops, variable definitions, arrays, etc. are JavaScript elements. It's not so obvious at first. By the way, this is a very good lesson if someone did not program in JS, only in C ++. The closeness of the syntax of the two languages ​​may be surprising.

The documentation section above explains these dependencies